# Parallel execution in azure devops release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, testcomplete

I am trying to run my testcomplete test suites using azure devops pipelines and I want to achieve parallel execution using the same ex: running two suites in two configured agents simultaneously/parallely. I am able to achieve it using the build pipeline by adding two agent jobs which on running executes both the jobs parallely. But the same thing I am not able to acheive using release pipeline.

FYI: I don't want to use the slicing feature as it divides test cases in runtime based on test cases or assemblies. I want to configure it before execution and then trigger it

Comment: @DanielMann I have tried adding agent nodes in same release pipeline and on execution of the pipeline, the agent jobs run in sequence while in build pipeline it executes parallely which is what I want for the release pipeline too

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the same situation in Release Pipeline.

When we add two jobs in a single release pipeline stage, the jobs will run in sequence by default.

[image]

[image]

We are not able to change this behavior for the time being.

To meet your requirement, you can refer to the following two methods:

1.If your job configuration is exactly the same, you can use the **Multi-Agent** option of the Agent job.

For example:

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

2.If you need to configure two jobs separately, you can add two stages and then add job in the stages respectively.

For example:

[image]

**Note:** You need to set the Triggers for the stages to **After Release**.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

If you can consider using slicing feature in release pipeline, we can use the **Multi-configuration** option.

[image]

Here are the steps:

Step1: Set Pipeline variable with the test case filter info:

[image]

Step2: Use the test case filter in the multi-configuration option.

Step3: Use the variable in test case filter field of the test task.

For example:

[image]

When you run the Pipeline, the agent job will run the test with the test case filter settings.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Multi job configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#multi-job-configuration)

Comment: Yeah I get that we have either the slicing option or the staging option. But 
1.With slicing option, we can't configure which scripts/tests will be run on which agent as it picks up from the agent pool
2.With multi staging I will get separate reports but I am trying to capture a single report like how I get it in the build pipeline.
Is there any option for that?

Comment: @GunacelanM May I know if the staging option can meet your requirement?

Comment: Yeah Staging looks fine but I am concerned about the reporting part where I get n different reports for n stages. Is it possible to capture it as a single report like how we do in the build pipeline

Comment: I can understand your concern. If you want to combine all test result from different stage, I am afraid that there is no method can do it for the time being. If you want to combine Code coverage result, you can consider using the extension:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Palmmedia.reportgenerator

Comment: @GunacelanM If you can consider using the slicing option, you may use the multi-configuration option. In this case, it can generate one report. Refer to my update in the answer

Comment: @GunacelanM Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: If I use slicing and multi configuration option, I cannot target my agent machines something like which set of test cases to be run on which agent..?

Comment: You can check if you can use the test category to determine which agent to run the target test cases.